# phantom reservation in Reservations database when trying to schedule a resouce/room

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

There is a phantom reservation from 9:30-10a everyday.  When I click on the particular reservation in the embedded scheduler I get an error message "The document specified by the link cannot be located within the link-to database."

Is there a way to clear the phatom reservation out?

Answer (score 0):

This document quite answer your question :

https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0031276

There is a corruption to fix.

In your case, do use the "rnrmgr" task instead of the "sched" as seen in the doc.
And so :

1. delete the resource doc in the busytime.nsf (clubusy if cluster)
2. issue the command : "tell rnrmgr validate yourResource/youORG"

There are several other options that you may issue with RNRMGR/SCHED tasks, that may help with other issues of that kind.